# Azure Stream Analytics. Pricing

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am looking at pricing information for Azure Stream Analytics using the Azure Pricing Calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/#stream-analytics378d63b3-303d-4548-afd0-bac5d4249611

I says that it cost 80 USD for 1 month (730 hours).

Is this the idle price?

If i don't send any data to Steam Analytics I will be charged 80 USD a month for having the service deployed. Correct?

Then op top of that I pay for my actual usage in form of streaming units, where a streaming unit, according to the FAQ, is a blend of compute, memory, and throughput.

Comment: why is this being down voted?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful Thank you. I do have another answer that says opposite. So I am going to create a new azure subscription. Deploy Stream Analytics and leave it there for 24 hours and then check the charges. If think that is the best way for me to find out what this will cost me

Comment: I confirm the answers below. Price is per hour of the service deployed, even if no data is sent. The service is actually running and ready to react in real-time to any event. If you don't plan to use the service for a long time we recommend to stop the job, so the charges stops. It can be restarted at any time.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. This is very useful for our test environment, that will be infrequently used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a cloud service, Stream Analytics is optimized for cost. There are no upfront costs involved - you only pay for the streaming units you consume, and the amount of data processed. There is no commitment or cluster provisioning required, and you can scale the job up or down based on your business needs.

While creating stream Analytics Job, if you created a Stream Analytics job with **streaming units = 1**, it will be billed **$0.11/hour**.

[image]

If you created a Stream Analytics job with **streaming units with N**, it will be billed **$0.11 * N/hour**.

Hope this helps. If you have any further query do let us know.

Comment: Will I still be charged if I stop the job?

Comment: The analytic streaming job will still be charged even when it is stopped. As soon as it is deployed, doesn't matter what the job status is (running/failed/stopped), you will still be charged.

Answer (score 2):

NO. You will pay only for what you use. For example if you configure 1 streaming unit and used 10 hours per month (10*0.11). If you configure 2 streaming unit and used 20 hours per month (20*0.11*2)

Answer (score 0):

> 1.If i don't send any data to Steam Analytics I will be charged 80 USD a
>   month for having the service deployed.

Quick answer is yes.Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-introduction#low-total-cost-of-ownership):

> As a cloud service, Stream Analytics is optimized for cost. There are
>   no upfront costs involved - you only pay for the streaming units you
>   consume, and the amount of data processed. There is no commitment or
>   cluster provisioning required, and you can scale the job up or down
>   based on your business needs.

SU is basis of ASA job. Choosing the number of required SUs for a particular job depends on the partition configuration for the inputs and the query that's defined within the job.More details,please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-streaming-unit-consumption#how-many-sus-are-required-for-a-job).

> 2.Then op top of that I pay for my actual usage in form of streaming
>   units, where a streaming unit, according to the FAQ, is a blend of
>   compute, memory, and throughput.

If your data is not updated in real time, or very small,maybe ASA is not your Best choice. You could follow some suggestions in this thread:[Azure Stream Analytics job expensive for small data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062045/azure-stream-analytics-job-expensive-for-small-data)

Comment: Is there any way to check how much amount is consumed by a particular SA job in azure portal ?